# SVG Path : last element goes behind?

Tags: svg

I thought that the last element present in a SVG path would be one on top. Here is the 2 pathes I am working on :

- The first one is here : http://jsfiddle.net/rakn0j4b/
- The second one is here : http://jsfiddle.net/gttgu8d8/

Now, when I "merge them" both together, here is what I do obtain : http://jsfiddle.net/x006fb9r/

As you can see, the last element goes "behind" the first. I also tried the opposite, aka putting the 2nd element before, but nothing changes.

Funnily enough, if I "repeat" the 2nd element (so my path is `1st element 2nd element 2nd element`), then the problem is corrected. Any hint on what's going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine the two parts, the simplest solution is to add them as separate `<path>` elements.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M110.0,30.0 v 1.0 h 600.0 v -1.0M110.0,40.0 v 1.0 h 600.0 v -1.0M110.0,50.0 v 1.0 h 600.0 v -1.0M110.0,60.0 v 1.0 h 600.0 v -1.0M110.0,70.0 v 1.0 h 600.0 v -1.0 M710.0,30.0 v 41.0 h 1.0 v -41.0 "></path>

    <path d="M110.0,30.0 l 6.0,0 0,41.0 -6.0,0 z m9.0,0.0 l 1.1999999,0 0,41.0 -1.1999999,0 z m5.0,14.5a2.5,2.5 0 1,0 5.0,0 a 2.5,2.5 0 1,0 -5.0,0 z m0.0,11.5a2.5,2.5 0 1,0 5.0,0 a 2.5,2.5 0 1,0 -5.0,0 z"></path>
</svg>
```

> I thought that the last element present in a SVG path would be one on top.

They are, but you were not creating two elements, you were creating a single path element with lots of subpaths.

If the subpaths in a path are overlapping, then the intercepting areas may or may not be filled depending on whether those areas are considered to be "inside" the path or not.  There are a couple of different algorithms for determining inside-ness.  You can control which algorithm is used using the `fill-rule` attribute.  However the default fill rule (`nonzero`) is one that generally draws most overlapping areas, though some intercepting areas may not ever be drawn because they are considered "oustide" by both algorithms.  This seems to be the case with your combined path.

If you want to ensure overlapping areas are drawn, use separate `<path>` elements.  As I have done above.